# Event independence

Tags: probability

I have the following in my lecture notes:

$$\Omega = \left\{ E_r, E_g, E_b, E_m \right\}$$

The above is for the colour of the faces of a tetrahedric die: red, green, blue, mixed (red and green and blue). Define $$R = \left\{ E_r,E_m\right\},\,\,\, G = \left\{ E_g, E_m \right\}, \,\,\, B = \left\{ E_b, E_m \right\}$$

It says that the above are pairwise independent but not collectively. I am probably wrong in my understanding here. Pairwise independent I thought is that the elementary events within these composite events are independent, i.e. if you take $R$ then $E_r$ and $E_m$ are independent. But apparently this understanding is flawed, because my lecturer follows to say that $$P(RG) = P(R)\cdot P(G)$$ which implies that $R$ and $G$ are independent.

But I can't see how this is the case, as $R$ and $G$ have an elementary event in common, namely $E_m$. What am I missing here?

Comment: $E_r$ and $E_m$ cannot be (in)dependent in this context. This because it are no *events*. The events $\{E_r\}$ and $\{E_m\}$ are dependent.

Comment: Events that have no outcome in common are disjoint. If one of them happens then it is for sure that the other will not happen. That implies that they are dependent (preassumed that both have positive probability). So it is to be expected that independent events have outcomes in common.

Comment: Oh so I mixed up my disjoint and independent definition. Mutually exclusive events is another name for the disjoint events, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events $R,G,B$ are *pairwise independent* iff any two of them (or any pair of them) are (is) independent. Mathematically $$P(RG)=P(R)P(G),\, P(RB)=P(R)P(B), \,P(GB)=P(G)P(B)$$ The events $R,G,B$ are *independent* or mutually independent (or collectively as you say) if any two of them and if any three of them are independent when taken together.

The following holds

> mutually independent $\implies \\ \not \Longleftarrow$ pairwise independent

Now, *independence* is very different than *disjoint-ness*. As your example shows two events can be independent even if they are not disjoint! Independence does not imply disjoint and disjoint does not imply independent.

1. Two events $R,G$ are *independent* iff: $P(RG)=P(R)P(G)$. Independence means that "knowing $R$ occurs, you do not know more or less about $G$ occured or not. It is equally probable that $G$ occurs and you can discard the information that $R$ occured."  (very informaly said).
2. Two events $R,G$ are *disjoint* iff: $P(RG)=0$. Disjoint-ness means that $R$ and $G$ cannot occur together. So, actually if two events (that occur with positive probability) are disjoint they cannot be independent(!) because knowing that the one occured implies directly that the other did not occur.

It is an (easy) exercise to show, that

> If $R,G$ are disjoint, then they are independent iff $P(R)=0$ or $P(G)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(R\cap G)=P(\{E_r,E_m\}\cap\{E_g,E_m\})=P(\{E_m\})=\frac14$

$P(R)\times P(G)=\frac24\times\frac24=\frac14$

The outcomes are equal so events $R$ and $G$ are independent.
Likewise it can be shown that $R$ and $B$ are independent and that $G$ and $B$ are independent. That means: $R,G,B$ are pairwise independent.

---

$P(R\cap G\cap B)=P(\{E_m\})=\frac14$

$P(R)P(G)P(B)=\frac24\frac24\frac24\neq\frac14$

This shows that $R,G,B$ are not dependent.

---

Events are *subsets* of $\Omega$. Observe that e.g $E_r$ is not a subset but an element of $\Omega$.

Comment: I can see that probabilities are equal and why from that standpoint they are independent because we have definition  $P (A|B)= P (A) $. But from the standpoint of the sets it doesn't make sense to me because both have a common event, so we know that if one happened it may be the case that the other happened too. Now that I have said it, it sounds as if they are independent.

Comment: What they have in common is not an event, but an outcome.